# Redirecting all PHP Request to router in Nginx rewrite (Tonic Framework)

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, url-rewriting

I've started working on a new RESTful API using the Tonic Framework.
I already have functioning code that I've tested over my apache box, but I'm now trying to move it to my Nginx machine.

I've tried converting this to nginx rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !router\.php$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule .* router.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

But none of my rules seem to work.

What i've tried so far is Trying to redirect all requests to /v2/router.php (the php file im trying to get to)

```
location /v2/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /v2/router.php;
}
```

This causes weird results such as all of my php files executing for some weird reason, etc...

Would appreciate your support on this.

Comment: P.S. Here's the entire configuration if that might be needed: https://gist.github.com/freak4pc/b2c7065743f5d6772262

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like

```
location /v2 {
    root <absolute folder path>/v2;
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /v2/router.php?/$1 last;
        break;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Its still trying to find the file in / instead in v2... so I'm guessing this isn't the exact solution

Comment: Does your URL has `v2` in it?

Comment: My bad- the problem was in my Router file. Thank you!